# How can I expose a service on multiple ports over HTTP in ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service in Kubernetes which I have to expose on multiple ports over HTTP.
I use Nginx-Ingress and was able to expose my service over Port 80 successfully.(`http://serviceA.example.com --> service-a:80`)

However I am not able to use a diffrent port for Http then Port 80.
How can I tell nginx-ingress to listen on Port 7049 aswell.

I've already tried to expose Port 7049 on the nginx Service and added the annotation `nginx.org/listen-ports: "80,7049"` to the nginx controller. Neither worked for me.

I expect the following output:

```
http://serviceA.example.com --> service-a:80

http://serviceA.example.com:7049 --> service-a:7049
```

ingress-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

my-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  - port: 7049
    targetPort: 7049
    name: symbols
  selector:
    app: my-service
```

my-service-ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservice.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Can you share the yaml files you are using for the serviceA and its ingress? Also do not change things in your ingress-controller. This is most likely something regarding your ingress only.

Answer (score 3):

Ingress Object is used to expose application **only** for HTTP and HTTPS Traffic.

> Ingress, added in Kubernetes v1.1, exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

[what-is-ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress)

You can have different type of routing such as path based or hostname based routing but the port  number for the nginx will be 80 or& 443.

If you want to expose  your application on different port than 80 and 443 , you need to use [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type service

Comment: Agree, the standard Ingress is just for the standard HTTP ports (80 & 443). If you want custom ports, you can check the Voyager implementation: https://appscode.com/products/voyager/8.0.1/guides/ingress/http/custom-http-port/

Comment: @RafałLeszko thanks for the comment, that's good to know  that we can expose is on different port nevertheless we still need to use HTTP protocol. For non-http, we need to use different solutions. correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you modify the service declaration for the Nginx ingress controller. In the Nginx [deploy.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/raw/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) you will find:

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
```

add the following snippet to use HTTP on port 7049 also:

```
    - name: http-symbols
      port: 7049
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
```

and redeploy the Nginx ingress controller with `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to expose ingress on non-standard port (i.e. other than 80/443) you can use **NodePort** type of service for that. By default NodePort type of service opens a random port on the node from the range **30000 - 32767** where the service becomes reachable. You'd need to override two things in such a case:

1) To override the default node port range use the following flag when starting your apiserver: `--service-node-port-range=7000-9000`

2) To force the assignment of the concrete port in the `NodePort` service use the following service deployment in your .yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 7049
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  selector:
    k8s-app: ingress-nginx
  type: NodePort
```